# How to do UDP without port forwarding

Tags: c#, udp, firewall, udpclient

I am creating an application in C#, It should send data with UDP.

Everything works fine until, I try to communicate with a PC that is on the internet behind a router.

How do I fix this so that I can use UDP without port forwarding?

Comment: I believe the answer may be UPnP. I don't know enough about it to actually know though.

Comment: Do you really need to use UDP?  UDP is ugly and dangerous.  My company lost a multi-100K contract thanks to UDP (in conjunction with Log4Net).

Comment: @Musi, even though it's not an answer per-se, I'd recommend you post a full answer saying what is so horrible about it.

Comment: @Earlz: no, because it doesn't actually answer his question. UDP is basically lower-level than, say, HTTP, so it's powerful but difficult to work with safely. In my case, UDP crashes ActiveSync (used to communicate between PC and Windows Mobile device) in a way that requires a reboot of the PC and a hard reset of the device. I learned about this during a seal-the-deal NetMeeting demo because my co-worker had enabled the Log4Net UDP appender without telling me (not that I would have had any idea how bad this was if he had told me). First time the app tried to write to the log - BAM!

Comment: It took me more than a day to figure out what had happened, by which time the client was looking elsewhere. What was especially infuriating was that there was absolutely no need for this to happen. Who on Earth needs to use UDP for remote logging?

Comment: @MusiGenesis that sounds more like an issue with Log4Net than UDP. There are cases where UDP is a better choice than TCP.

Comment: @Foole: it's more like an issue with my co-worker than either Log4Net or UDP. However, my point was that UDP tends to have unexpected side effects (as exemplified by my comment and this question). If you enjoy dealing with unexpected side effects, I recommend UDP.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best hope is [UDP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching).

My understanding of it is that each host sends data to the other.  This tricks the firewall/NAT into thinking the connection had already been established.

Comment: Hi, i read about this "UDP hole punching", but i didn't found any examples of it in c#. can you show some of it?

Comment: No, I'm not aware of any.  I think this is because each implementation is unique.